# Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * not working?

Tags: mod-python, cors

Classic "Origin ... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" problem.  Two machines serve contents for the same website.  When machine A does a `$('#main').load('link_to_resource_on_B')` via jquery, machine B serves up the content with mod_python, adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.  But for some reason, this still does not work.  I tested this on Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer.  And I tested via command line to check the response header, it seems `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is successfully in the header from B.  See below.  What could i be missing?

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /tests/python/test/env HTTP/1.1
host: 10.0.1.10 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 27 Feb 2012 02:05:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Are there any custom headers that are set by the client? Custom headers (or non-GET HTTP methods) could trigger a preflight request, which needs additional handling.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, @monsur.  You are right, it was the OPTION header, and wasn't handled as it seems.  A little research also told me that my jquery was too old.  The newer jquery (since 1.5.2) deliberately avoids using customer header.  So it boils down to, I upgraded my jquery, and my headache went away.  

For those others who suffer with the same symptom, this link provides me the second half of the enlightenment.  [http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/](http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/)

Comment: @josh3736, thanks for helping me format my initial post.  That was my first post.  Will know what to do next time.

Answer (score 7):

Enabling `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response is not sufficient. Server side implementation should also provide proper handling for [pre-flight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). Particularly, the following HTTP headers must be set in the OPTIONS response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
```

Consider replacing wildcard with the list of domains allowed to access the cross-origin server.

Have in mind that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header must be also set in the following GET & POST responses.

Other HTTP headers such as `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` might be also needed in OPTIONS response in case non-standard HTTP headers are used.

Great article explaining CORS can be found [here](https://reflectoring.io/complete-guide-to-cors/)