# Strange behaviour - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: php, ajax, http, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load www.mysite/ajax.php **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header**
>   is present on the requested resource. Origin 'www.mysite' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

This occurs when I try to process an Ajax request. 

 
This is fixed by adding:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com/');
```

However, this only works when I `echo` something (it can be anything) after this line:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com/'); 
  echo "<span></span>"; //if this is removed, I'm presented with the error
  require_once 'functions.php';
  ...
?>
```

When the `echo` is emitted, I'm once again presented with the error. 
**Can anyone explain this peculiar behaviour?**

---

#### EDIT

Could it have anything to do with the structure of my Ajax call?

```
var formdata = $( "#calculator_form" ).serialize();
    $.get( "ajax.php", formdata). done( function( data ) {
        $('.result').html(data); // Printing result into result class div
    });
```

---

#### EDIT 2

This can be found in the error_log:

> malformed header from script. Bad header=<>... User unknown: php-cgi,
>   referer: http://www.example.com/

**NOTE** - both `ajax.php` and `index.php` are on the same domain even though the responses and errors would suggest elsewise.

Comment: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: both of those should explain it to you

Comment: Did you read my question fully? how does an `echo` following the `header()` make it work, but without the `echo` is breaks.

Comment: how are you making the ajax call?

Comment: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459949/access-control-allow-origin-not-working)

Comment: I added my ajax call :)

Comment: there's your problem: [jQuery AJAX cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: How come if I echo something after the inclusion of `header()` it still works?

Comment: possibly because if nothing is output on the screen it's not the default json request that ajax is asking for so the server throws a fit saying that it doesn't have json to give.

Comment: there's a lot of stuff after the `echo` , it needs to be directly after or it breaks. Baffling.

Comment: @iam-decoder please take a look at my edit

Comment: Try changing `http://www.example.com/` to `example.com`